# Download link to CSV file in the mail using spring boot

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, email, spring-boot

I am generating csv in my code, It takes some time to generate. So, I am sending an email with link once the csv file is generated. When I click that, getting 404 not found error. When I have the same link in the html, I am able to download it. Any insight or sample to refer

```
 Sample Link -http://localhost:9090/api/report/file?fileName=filename.csv
```

Java code to download the report

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "api/report/file")
public void downloadCSV(HttpServletResponse response, @RequestParam("fileName") String fileName) throws IOException {

    File file = new File(fileName);
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);

    response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
    // Response header
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\"");
    // Read from the file and write into the response
    OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int len;
    while ((len = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        os.write(buffer, 0, len);
    }
    os.flush();
    os.close();
    is.close();
}
```

Comment: Can you show that link?

Comment: @yariash Edited the question

Comment: Would need to see some of your code around the handler used to respond to the /api/report URI.

Comment: @ShawnClark Updated the question with code

Comment: Hopefully not just a typo on cutting/pasting into SO but it looks like your sample link compared to your @RequestMapping is missing the "/file" on the end of the path. Am I seeing that wrong?

Comment: @ShawnClark Sorry. It is a typo

Comment: The code looks okay. When using the email link... what is showing up in the Spring logs around the request? Do you get any insight into what the framework is trying to do? If you have the Spring Actuator dependency you can check the /trace endpoint to see the last few requests (http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html)

Comment: Separate comment around security... By allowing someone to provide the filename you are opening yourself up to an attack whereby they can provide a absolute url (e.g. /etc/conf/some.conf) and be able to retrieve any file on your server. In these type of use cases you want to only expose the report identifier then have a dictionary lookup of the identifier to a filename. Something like:

`GET http://localhost/api/report/1/result`

Answer (score 0):

Add GET method to this mapping: `@RequestMapping(value = "api/report/file")`